# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/...index.php on line 4

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching around on google, but i cant find the solution on what is wrong with this line. What is wrong with this line?

Here is the code:

```
$query = end(explode('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?

Comment: If `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is `'/test'` your code will erroneously  assign the whole string to `$query` ... I don't think that's intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to seperate it out since you cannot use `end()` like that.

```
$query = explode('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$query = end($query);
```

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

> The array. This array is passed by reference because it is modified by
>   the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a
>   function returning an array because only actual variables may be
>   passed by reference.

Comment: @FlikFlak While this code will work, do note that it will return the wrong results if the query string is empty (question mark is missing).

Answer (score 0):

Most developers would say that `end()` requires a variable instead of an expression and that because of that you have to separate out your code into two statements.

While it's wrong to rely on this particular behaviour, the following hack will work:

```
$query = end((explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
```

*Notice the extra parentheses?*

Besides that, if you still don't like having two separate statements, you should use other string functions, e.g.:

```
$query = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'), 1);
```

In fact, this is the more correct approach; imagine that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` didn't contain a question mark; your method would then return the full string.

Comment: I think for clarity of code and to follow guidelines it would be better to separate them out. Just because a ***hack*** works doesn't mean it should be used.

Comment: @CarlMarkham Did you miss the part where I say "while it's wrong to rely on this particular behaviour ..."? That said, his approach was wrong any way.